# Metro App Detect Printer Charm Open and Close

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, charms-bar

I have a metro application and would like to detect when the Printer charm is opened and closed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PrintManager`'s `PrintTaskRequested` event. When Printer charm bar is opened, that event occurs. `PrintTaskRequested` event do printing using `PrintTask` objects. It has event called `Completed` event. It ouccurs when print task is completed.

MSDN documentation of [PrintTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.printing.printtask) class

MSDN documentation of [PrintManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.printing.printmanager.aspx) class

XAML

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Content="Print" />
</Grid>
```

C#

```
public sealed partial class BlankPage2 : Page
{
    public BlankPage2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        PrintManager printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
        printMan.PrintTaskRequested += PrintTaskRequested;
    }

    private void PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Printer Opened");
        //TODO:
        PrintTask printTask = e.Request.CreatePrintTask(....);
        printTask.Completed += printTask_Completed;
    }

    void printTask_Completed(PrintTask sender, PrintTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        //TODO:
    }


    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: What strategy do I use for detecting closed?